# vagrant - constantly syncing folder setup

Tags: windows, centos, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I am trying build a centos7 vm at my windows10 using virtualbox. I am using cento/7 box.
it by default using rsync for syncing folder and I don't really like it as I would have to open an extra cmd just to run `vagrant rsync-auto` for constant syncing.
I tried to use nfs but not successful.
Here is my vagrantfile.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/sync", type: "nfs"
end
```

and when I tried to run it. It gave me this.

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` home_vagrant_sync /home/vagrant/sync
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` home_vagrant_sync /home/vagrant/sync

The error output from the last command was:

mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'
```

I noticed that changes made by host will be synced to guest but not the other way round. I want to make the folder like a shared folder both guest and host can apply changes to it. Any best approaches to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply you got is telling you to install Virtual Box guest additions. This is a separate installation action you have to perform on top of installing Virtual Box. Did you install Virtual Box Guest Additions?

Comment: Thanks. After installing the VBoxGuestAdditions, it works. I followed the manual here(https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) but I found it is a little outdated. It should be the "optical drives" in "Devices" being clicked to mount the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso. Then, use the command "mount /dev/cdrom /mnt" to mount the iso to guest vm. It would then be easier to follow the manual. I am thinking is there anyway to install the Virtualbox guest additions through the vagrantfile?